# Jolt transform spec to union two objects within an array based on some condition

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I want to merge objects where personId and visitDate of objects is same else keep the object as it is in the array

Sample Input -

```
[
  {
    "personId": 1,
    "visitDate": "1453545",
    "htn": 1,
    "dm": 0
  },
  {
    "personId": 1,
    "visitDate": "1453545",
    "htn": 1,
    "dm": 1
  },
  {
    "personId": 2,
    "visitDate": "4453545",
    "htn": 1,
    "dm": 1
  },
  {
    "personId": 3,
    "visitDate": "6453545",
    "htn": 1,
    "dm": 1
  }
]
```

Sample Output

```
[
  {
    "personId": 1,
    "visitDate": "1453545",
    "htn": 1,
    "dm": 1
  },
  {
    "personId": 2,
    "visitDate": "4453545",
    "htn": 1,
    "dm": 1
  },
  {
    "personId": 3,
    "visitDate": "6453545",
    "htn": 1,
    "dm": 1
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

See whether the below spec helps, segregate the object with respect to personId and then use cardinality to remove the duplicates, then shift the object to the array.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "@personId[]"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```